# Send propertybag over winsock?

Tags: vb6, winsock, propertybag

I am having trouble sending a `propertybag` over `winsock`. I have a client/server application that sends images through using a `propertybag`. I convert the `propertybag` into a byte array and try to send it over `winsock` and then when I convert the byte array back to a `propertybag`, it cant seem to read it. It looks like the data was corrupted when it was sent.

**Client(sending propertybag)**

```
Dim pb As PropertyBag
Dim byt() As Byte

Set pb = New PropertyBag

pb.WriteProperty "picc", Image1.Picture
byt = pb.Contents

Winsock1.SendData byt
```

**Server(Receiving propertybag)**

```
   Dim byt() As Byte
   Dim pb As PropertyBag

   Set pb = New PropertyBag

   Winsock1.GetData byt, vbByte

   pb.Contents = byt
   Image1.Picture = pb.ReadProperty("picc")
```

**The error I received:**

```
Run-time error '327':
Data value named 'picc' not found
```

When I try to do execute the code in a single program without `winsock`, it works just fine. The problem occurs when I send the byte array over `winsock`.

Comment: i would write both byte arrays (sent and received) to a file and compare the differences

Comment: One `SendData` call can't be reliably received via one `GetData` call.  This is the "packet fallacy."  You do not send data in user-defined "packets" but send stream fragments and receive stream fragments that are not the same length (and may be as small as 1 byte per data arrival event).  TCP is not a datagram protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people also utilize the ADO stream object (add reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 or whatever version) by going to **Project** -> **References**.

[Here is a working example you can download using a PropertyBag as well as the ADO stream object.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?689301-RESOLVED-Send-image-betweeb-two-apps-using-IPC&p=4226201&viewfull=1#post4226201)

It's called **PicturePicture.zip** and written by a very Winsock & client/server-knowledgeable programmer.